# How do i render descriptive text for each FlatList item?

Tags: react-native

```
<FlatList
          data={[
            {id: '1'},
            {name: 'snus'},
            {pris: '32'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.item}>
                                    <Text>{item.pris}{item.name}{item.id}</Text>
                                  </View>}
/>
```

When i render the items like this, they get properly formatted and each view is rendered as a listitem: [click here for visual confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyrMo.jpg).

however, when i add descriptive text in front of each JSX element, it gets rendered for all the listitems, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8R7X.jpg).

Code:

```
renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.item}>
                         <Text>pris: {item.pris}</Text>
                        </View>}
```

how do i solve this conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `renderItem` prop

```
renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.item}>
                         <Text>pris: {item.pris}</Text>
                        </View>}
```

is properly formatted.
The problem is the array of data that you're passing to the `FlatList`. Each item is supposed to have `id`, `name` and `pris` props. Instead you are creating an array with three objects, once per prop.
I think your intention is to give an array with this structure instead:

```
[{id: '1', name: 'snus', pris: '32'}, { id: '2', name: 'snus_2', pris: '23'}]
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :) so I'll be glad if you'd consider to accept the answer